# Type of identifier does not agree with its usage as "boolean" type - VHDL in Quartus

Tags: vhdl, fpga, identifier, hdl, quartus

I'm developing a simple buffering system in VHDL. I get the error I mentioned in the title for "empty" whenever I try to compile. I don't know why it won't let me invert a std_logic type. I've also been getting errors about the comparisons. For some reason, it doesn't recognize the ">" and "<" operators on status_as_int and the thresholds.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY Buffer_Controller is
    port (
    empty               :   in std_logic;
    full                :   in std_logic;
    filling_status      :   in std_logic_vector(14 downto 0); 
    read_thresh         :   in integer;                         
    write_thresh        :   in integer;
    read_now            :   out std_logic;
    write_now           :   out std_logic
    );
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE ctrl of Buffer_Controller is

signal status_as_int : integer;

BEGIN

status_as_int <= to_integer(unsigned(filling_status));

read_now <= '1' when (NOT(empty) AND status_as_int > read_thresh) else
                '0';
                
write_now <= '1' when (NOT(full) AND status_as_int < write_thresh) else
                 '0';

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Comment: In -2008 the condition operator to evaluate to a value as '0' - `read_now  <= '1' when (?? (NOT empty)) AND (status_as_int > read_thresh) else '0';`. Unlike in the original conditional assignment statement all the parentheses here are required by syntax or semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty` and `full` are not booleans. They're `std_logic`, which is a user defined type (defined in the ieee.std_logic_1164 library). That's not a boolean.

Yes, you *can* invert them, but the result will still be `std_logic`. (The overloaded implementation of `NOT` for `std_logic` is also defined in the ieee.std_logic_1164 library).

To convert to boolean, You need to compare them to something that can be interpreted as `std_logic`, e.g.

```vhdl
read_now <= '1' when
    empty = '0' AND
    status_as_int > read_thresh
       else '0';
```